# Возможность прокрутки без видимого скролл-бара

Tags: html, css, прокрутка

Как можно реализовать возможность скролла без видимого сролл-бара?

Пример кода на [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DarkVss/29johLa4/1/)

```js
var rotate = 0;
$('.news-switch').click(function() {
  if (rotate >= 360) rotate = 0;
  $('.news-switch>img').css('transform', 'rotate(' + (rotate += 180) + 'deg)');
  if (rotate == 180) $('.news-switch').css('width', '350px');
  else $('.news-switch').css('width', '110px');
  $('#news-block').toggle();
});
```

```css
#all-news {
  margin-top: -21px;
  position: fixed;
}
.news-switch {
  width: 133px;
  background-color: #008cba;
  border: 1px solid #006687;
  padding: 5px 10px 5px 10px;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
  z-index: 100;
}
.bottom {
  bottom: 0px;
  width: 350px;
}
.bottom>img {
  transform: rotate(180deg) !important;
}
.news-switch>img {
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-top: 5px;
  float: right;
}
#news-block {
  display: none;
  background-color: #008cba;
  border: 1px solid #006687;
  padding: 40px 5px 45px 5px;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  color: white;
  width: 350px;
  height: 500px;
}
.news {
  background-color: #5bc0de;
  padding: 1px 7px 30px 7px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}
.news h4 {
  text-align: center;
}
.news p {
  text-indent: 15px;
}
.news a {
  color: rgba(21, 20, 20, 0.37);
  text-decoration: none;
  float: right;
}
.news a:hover {
  color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  padding: 5px;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='all-news'>
  <div class='news-switch'>Новости
    <img src='/upload/arrow.png' />
  </div>
  <div id='news-block'>

    <div class='news'>
      <h4>Заголовок</h4>
      <p>Текст
        <br>како-нибудь
        <br>чтобы был</p>
      <a href="#">Подробнее</a>
    </div>
    <div class='news'>
      <h4>Заголовок</h4>
      <p>Текст
        <br>како-нибудь
        <br>чтобы был
        <br>чтобы был
        <br>чтобы был
        <br>чтобы был
        <br>чтобы был
        <br>чтобы был
        <br>чтобы быавыаываыаываываываываываываваыв ывацуак цуацку кауцеацецекцеукеукеукеукеукеукел
        <br>чтобы был
        <br>чтобы был</p>
      <a href="#">Подробнее</a>
    </div>
    <div class='news'>
      <h4>Заголовок</h4>
      <p>Текст
        <br>како-нибудь
        <br>чтобы был
        <br>чтобы был
        <br>чтобы был
        <br>чтобы был
        <br>чтобы был
        <br>чтобы был
        <br>чтобы быавыаываыаываываываываываываваыв ывацуак цуацку кауцеацецекцеукеукеукеукеукеукел
        <br>чтобы был
        <br>чтобы был</p>
      <a href="#">Подробнее</a>
    </div>
    <div class='news'>
      <h4>Заголовок</h4>
      <p>Текст
        <br>како-нибудь
        <br>чтобы был
        <br>чтобы был
        <br>чтобы был
        <br>чтобы был
        <br>чтобы был
        <br>чтобы был
        <br>чтобы быавыаываыаываываываываываываваыв ывацуак цуацку кауцеацецекцеукеукеукеукеукеукел
        <br>чтобы был
        <br>чтобы был</p>
      <a href="#">Подробнее</a>
    </div>




    <div class='news-switch bottom'>Новости
      <img src='/upload/arrow.png' />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Отлавливать mousewheel событие и изменять положение элемента вручную. Для Jquery есть отдельный плагин mousewheel .

Comment: Вы имеете ввиду примерно так: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/29johLa4/2/) ?

Comment: а не вариант передвигаться по якорям ? к примеру как делают лендинг page , могу скинуть пример этого

Comment: @AlexanderIgorevich, только если Ваш пример ограничен Google Chrome, в остальных случаях это не поможет. Браузер FF не отрабатывает, IE даже код автора не отрабатывает.

Comment: @AlexanderIgorevich,да.почти-только нижний блок новость убегает тоже))

Comment: @LenovoID,не-якори не то.просто в блоке может быть инфы чуть,а может быть пздц много))

Comment: ну и что ? сама технология якорей выставляет нужный контейнер под самый верх и как бы в центр , не промахнётесь , могу скинуть пример

Comment: @LenovoID,пользовался этим-но просто в данном случае это не подходит под общую концепцию дизайна,наверно проще версталу отдать_-_

Comment: вы скиньте пример -- хоть увидеть - что там не подходит , в архив запакуйте и скиньте на яндэкс диск , или в dropbox , или на cloud.mail.ru

Comment: @LenovoID,на Jsfield скинул примерное оформление-проект сам весит не мало.полноценная система уже(

Answer (score 1):

Для того что бы скрыть скролл бары на странице в вебкит браузерах

```
::-webkit-scrollbar { 
    display: none; 
}
```